# How to print request body in Koa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, koa, koa-router

I have an app where I need to send data from `React` frontend to `Koa` server. Problem is that I have no idea how to print out request body in Koa.

In `React` I run this code on click

```js
fetch("/metafield", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        key: "key",
        value: "value",
        value_type: "string",
        namespace: "namespace",
      }),
    });
```

Just a simple fetch with body on Koa server endpoint.

In `Koa` I have this

```js
router.post("/metafield", (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.request.body);
  });
```

For some reason this returns empty object `{}`.

I also tried with

```js
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");
const server = new Koa();
server.use(bodyParser());
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser),
but the output is still the same. After that I tried adding bodyParser to koa-router like

```js
const router = new Router();
router.use(bodyParser());
```

but still I get empty object in Koa app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. The solution is so simple.

It worked when I added

```js
headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
```

when sending request with `fetch`

Request should look like this now

```js
fetch("/metafield", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        key: "key",
        value: "value",
        value_type: "string",
        namespace: "namespace",
      }),
    });
```